# JavaScript beginner: How to restart a loop

Tags: javascript

Once the user guesses the right number I need to ask if the user would like to play again. As it is the loop will just repeat itself but what I need is the prompt box to ask if you would like to play again. If the user replies yes the loop will initiate again until the answer is guessed

```
<HTML>    
    <HEAD>    
    </HEAD>    
    <BODY
        <FORM NAME="testform">
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <BR>
        </FORM>

        <INPUT id="attempts" TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="" />
        <INPUT id="zero" TYPE="button" NAME="resetbox" VALUE="Reset " onclick="reset()" />

        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            varattempts = 0;
            x = Math.round((Math.random()*19))+1;
            var tip; 

            tip=prompt("Do you want to play a game?")

            while(tip.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == "y")    
            {    
                var Guess;
                document.getElementById('attempts').value = 0;
                do 
                {    
                    Guess = prompt("Pick a number between 1 and 20","")
                    if (Guess === null) break;
                    document.getElementById('attempts').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('attempts').value)+1
                } while (Guess!=x);

                if (Guess == x)     
                {               
                    alert("You guessed right!")                 
                }
            }               
            function reset()                
            {
                varattempts=0;
                document.getElementById('attempts').value = 'Attempts: 0'; 
            }
        </SCRIPT>  
    </BODY>    
</HTML>
```

Comment: I would reread the chapter in your book.

Comment: `varattempts = 0;` looks like a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Put your loop inside another loop. Loopedy loop dee doop.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest it to create a function for running an iteration.  When that iteration finishes, the function returns and you ask if they want to play again.  If so, you call the function again.

Put all your other code in a function named `play()`:

```
function play() {
    // all your other code here
}

// Then call that function in a loop, return true from play() if the user is done
// and doesn't wish to be asked if they want to play again
var done;
do {
    done = play();
} while (!done || window.confirm("Do you want to play again?"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could put the main bit in a function, then when its time to reset, return false and recall the function depending on the prompt box. if its yes call it if not just do nothing or maybe display some different text?

```
varattempts = 0;
```

looks like a mistake

looks like a messed up way to write something simple imo.